# Scheduler is not running due to the cron expression

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Spring 3.0.2 version to run my Java/Flex application.
The task is that "Every new year at 12.00 A.M I need to reset a column value to zero on database". But the scheduler is not executing the configured method.

But if I change the corn expression to other form, for eg: run every the scheduler  for every 50 secs it works perfectly.

Below is the cron expression which has been configured on properties file.

```
cron1.expression = 0 0 0 1 1 ?
```

**Configuration in Application context**.

```
<task:annotation driven/>

<util:properties id="javaScheduler" location="WEB-INF/javaScheduler.properties"/>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="javaScheduler"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="schedulerDAO" method="updateSampleRegistrationSeqno" 
    cron="#{javaScheduler['cron1.expression']}"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

**Configured Method:**

```
public void updateSampleRegistrationSeqno() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        logging.info("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----Updating sample registration series code in Seqnotransgenerator of table name All ---->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

        //String sp = "exec dbo.sp_SequenceUpdateNewYear";

        getJdbcTemplate().execute("update SequencenoTransGenerator set nsequenceno = 0 where stablename = 'All'");

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logging.info("Exception occured at updateSampleRegistrationSeqno :------->"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to modify the xml file repeatedly and also its easy to maintain the cron expression on properties file if your application needs to have multiple task schedulers

Comment: How you expect to check crob expression that will be executed/seen only on new year?

Comment: Once I configured the cron expression the rest of the things will be taken care by Executor service.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines in your application context:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/properties/app.properties"/>
```

or

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/properties/app.properties"/>

<task:annotation-driven></task:annotation-driven>
```

Schedule task:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cronexp}")
public void executeTask() {
    //execute sql script

}
```

Add this cron expression in your properties file:

```
cronexp=0 0 0 1 1 ?
```

It worked for me.

Note: at location you should provide you properties path